# "render as JSON" is display JSON as text instead of returning it to AJAX call as expected

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm navigating to the `index` action of `MyController`.  Some of the code on the `index` page is making an AJAX call back to `myAction` in `MyController`.  I expect `myAction` action to return some data as JSON to my AJAX call so I can do something with the data client side, but instead of returning the data as JSON like I want, the data is being displayed as text.

Example of my Grails controller:

```
class MyController {
    def index() {
        render( view: "myView" )
    }

    def myAction {
        def mapOfStuff = [ "foo": "foo", "bar": "bar" ]
        render mapOfStuff as JSON
    }
}
```

Example of my JavaScript:

```
$( function() {
    function callMyAction() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: base_url + '/myController/myAction',
            success: function( data ) {
                $(function() {
                    if( data.foo ) {
                        alert( data.foo );
                    }
                    if( data.bar ) {
                        alert( data.bar );
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What I expect is that my page will render, then my JavaScript will be called, then two alerts will display.  Instead the JSON array is displayed as text in my browser window:

```
{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}
```

At this point the last segment of the URL in my address bar is `myAction` and not `index`.  Now if I manually enter the URL of the index page and press refresh, all works as expected.

I have half a dozen AJAX calls I do the exact same way and none of them are having problems.  What is the deal here?

**UPDATE #1:**

I have noticed something.  When I set a break point in the `index` action of `MyController` and another one in the `myAction` action, the break point in `myAction` gets hit BEFORE the break point in `index` immediately following login, even though I am navigating to the `index`.  In fact, the breakpoint in the `index` action never gets hit.  This is obviously closer to the root cause of my problem, but why is it happening?

**UPDATE #2:**

I'm using Spring Security and I notice that even though I have the default URL set to...

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/myController'
```

... the break point in the "index" action of `MyController` never gets hit when I login, yet `myView` is rendered properly.  What kind of black magic is Spring Security doing that it can load my view without going through my controller?

**UPDATE #3:**

I have found a solution to this issue, and the problem was that Spring Security was doing something weird in the background.  So I just added `alwaysUseDefault` to my config and set it to true, like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
```

Now I hit the breakpoint set in the `index` action of `MyController` before the breakpoint in `myAction` is hit just as I would expect to happen.  Unfortunatly this solution is not optimal because a user is now ALWAYS redirected to the `defaultTargetUrl` after login, even if they were trying to navigate to a different page.

Though this solution kind of solves my problem, it raises the question, how was Spring Security redirecting to my `defaultTargetUrl` which was set like this...

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/myController'
```

... without going through the `index` action of `MyController`?

Comment: def mapOfStuff = [ "foo": "foo", "bar":]... Is that a typo?

Comment: Not a typo, it works with our without quotes.

Comment: But you didn't specify the value. "bar": (???). Is that a typo?

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a typo.  Thanks, edited.

Comment: There is definitely no black magic going on, you are just doing something incorrectly. My guess is that the code that is the problem is not included in your post.

Comment: @JamesKleeh Well James, the fact that the Spring Security defaultTargetUrl setting does redirect me to the page I want and does not hit any breakpoints in my controller action suggests that there is something going on in the background that is not blatantly obvious.  Otherwise my breakpoint would be hit everytime Grails rendered the page in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
def mapOfStuff = [ foo: "foo", bar:"bar"]
```

instead of using the keys as Groovy strings.

Comment: That works fine, but does not solve my problem.  See my updated question for more details.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, don't `render mapOfStuff as JSON`, but `return mapOfStuff as JSON`. It will assign a proper content-type header to a response.

`render()` is just a function that returns a `String` that gets rendered as `text/html`, as Grails cannot detect what is in there. `JSON` type, OTOH, is rendered with a proper content-type.

Comment: In the process of looking for a solution I did try `return` instead of `render`, many times in fact.  When I did that I got a page does not exist error.  In hindsight I know I was getting that error because the `index` action had never been hit.

Answer (score 0):

Set approporiate **response header** explicitly.

```
render(contentType: "text/json") {  
  def mapOfStuff = [ "foo": "foo", "bar": "bar" ]
}
```